# Is it possible to slice through a list for an if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried to find an example of something like this taking place. But I have yet to actually find out if it's possible. From reading list documentation i can iterate through a list by doing the following _FILTER[0:48].

Is there a way to make a statement like the one below work?

```
_FILTER = ['filter','filter2','etc']

for link in links:
    if link != _FILTER[0:48]
        do_something
```

I want the _FILTER[0:48] to be treated as an and, what I mean by that is I need all of the _FILTER options. 
e.g.

```
if link != _FILTER[0] and if link != _FILTER[1]..._FILTER[48]
```

Comment: @limelights I think he needs `if link not in _FILTER[0:48]`.

Comment: are there more than 48 or is that just a big number to ensure all? because simply doing:  if not link in _FILTER would work if the later

Comment: @Maciek of course - just a miss, sorry!

Comment: @gkusner the 48 is just how many filter strings are contained in the list. So you're saying that I can just ref. the list as a whole and it will iterate through it?

Comment: then not limiting the if would work and would be a better choice if it ever does get added to

Comment: Thank you all for your help, got everything working right! Sorry for wording the question so poorly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the general case:

```
_FILTER = ['filter','filter2','etc']

for link in links:
    if link not in _FILTER:
        do_something
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what 'links' is, in this case...

if links is a iterable of list and you are looking to see  if one of those lists matches your slice. Yes, it is possible. 
ex:

```
filter_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
link_list = [['2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2'] ['3', '4', '5']]

for link in link_list:
   if link != filter_list[0:2]:
       print('no match, do stuff')
```

This will  'do stuff' on the first and last index of 'link_list' but `list_list[1]` does equal the `filter_list` slice and will not 'do stuff'.

If you are just trying to do stuff if the link index is not in the `filter_list` I would use the 'not in' keywords instead.

Comment: This isn't OP's use case. Where does the list of lists thing come from? Its also not clear, even if you had a sublist like this that it would be desirable as `['1', '2']` would match but `['2', '1']` wouldn't (meaning its order dependent).

Comment: @tdelaney; I was trying to illustrate a way to accomplish what I interpreted  OP was trying to do.  It seems as though I am mistaken by the general discussion moving towards 'not in' keyword instead of searching for equality of the slice with 'link'